# SAS: Adding observation and fill forward

Tags: sas, append, rows

I want to add an observation in SAS per group at a certain time and fill forward all values (except the time). I don't want to do it manually with datalines and proc append. Is there another way? 
In the example: always insert a row per security at exactly 10:00am and use the value from the one above:

```
Security Time Value
ABC 9:59 2
ABC 10:01 3
.
.
.
DCE 9:58 9 
DCE 10:01 3
.
.
```

Output:

```
Security Time Value
ABC 9:59 2
ABC 10:00 2
ABC 10:01 3
.
.
.
DCE 9:58 9
DCE 10:00 9
DCE 10:01 3
.
.
```

Thankful for any help!

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can use `proc sql` to insert row:

```
PROC SQL;
    INSERT INTO table_name
    VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
QUIT;
```

OR

```
PROC SQL;
    INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
    VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
QUIT;
```

Comment: And how can i fill forward from the last observation then? (Given I inserted a time in between two time sorted observations, by group)